# Which ways are there to knock out a dinosaur?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

As stated in the title I want to know which ways there are to knock out a dinosaur. I know that you can use tranq arrows and the scorpion, but I've also heard that shooting a dinosaur's head with a slingshot is supposed to help with knocking it out (did not test that though).

So what else can you use to knock out a dinosaur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To knock out a creature, here are some of the more basic weapons and creatures you can use:

- Narcoberries / Narcotics (if you're able to force feed the creature)
- Bare fists
- Slingshot
- Wooden club
- Tranq arrows (with bow)
- Tranq darts (with rifle)
- Electric prod
- Scorpion (attacks raise torpor)
- Frog (attacks raise torpor)

There are more weapons / devices and creatures, but depending on your patch, you may not have them all. Here is [the most authoritative list](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Torpor) of torpor-causing methods I could find.

Comment: I'll add that you can also use Equus, the attack also raise torpor

Answer (score 1):

The Equus statistically is the best Dino for knocking out things as it’s buck attack does 3.4 torpor per damage vs the scorpions 2.9 torpor per damage. The crossbow is nice as trans arrows are cheap, but if you don’t worry about resource cost then yeah the shocking  tranq dart is the best.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to knock out a dino is to use a shocking tranq arrow with a long neck rifle. The best creature to knock out a dino is the patchy, but don't use the dinos to knock out creatures. It's not useful. But what you should do is get a bear trap or a large bear trap to trap them or a bola or chain bola best way is bear trap or go up on a rock were they cant hit you and start shooting it with tranqs.

For extra facts, shooting a tranq in a trikes head or a patchys head will do less torpor damage, but with other dinos it gives them more torpor damage. A tranq arrow with a cross bow to a parasaurs head knocks it out instantly if its bellow level 20.